# Stopping MySQL delete query before completion

Tags: mysql

I was trying to delete some rows from my MySQL table with 200 Million rows. While it works fine in the beginning, it slows down drastically after a few hours. I was hoping I can stop the query for now and restart it and hence make it happen faster. Will my database remain intact after that?

Comment: What ENGINE are you using?

Comment: Can you add the result of "Explain" using your query?

Comment: engine was innodb
the query was  delete from pagelinks where pl_namespace <> 0;

Never used explain but I can google if u want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can terminate your current delete operation by terminating the session in which it was started. For that you can use already mentioned `KILL` statement issued from other session, or terminate client process if your delete was issued from some client code (e.g. php).

It's not very clear what you mean by *intact*. If you mean integrity of your table then yes it should be intact. If you mean will it be rolled back then it depends on context in which delete was issued.

To delete the remaining rows after abruption in batches and assuming that you `DELETE` from one table (meaning you're not using multi-table syntax) you can try to use `LIMIT` clause.

```
DELETE 
  FROM table_name
 WHERE ...
 LIMIT 10000 -- or any other appropriate batch size
```

This way you'll be able to delete n (10000) rows a time.

Comment: Thanks for help
however it finished after a day so didn't need it :)
by intact I meant if the rows that are deleted till now would remain deleted. I was wondering if I could kill the query and start it again in order to run it faster?

Answer (score 2):

See [KILL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html) chapter on the docs.

> **KILL [CONNECTION | QUERY] thread_id**
>
> Each connection to mysqld runs in
>   a separate thread. You can see which threads are running with the SHOW
>   PROCESSLIST statement and kill a thread with the KILL thread_id
>   statement.
>
> During UPDATE or DELETE operations, the kill flag is checked after
>   each block read and after each updated or deleted row. If the kill
>   flag is set, the statement is aborted. Note that if you are not using
>   transactions, the changes are not rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Mysql Command line Client like this

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------
-----+
| Id | User   | Host            | db     | Command | Time | State | Info
     |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------
-----+
|  2 | adroit | localhost:49857 | dbname | Sleep   |  339 |       | NULL
     |
|  3 | adroit | localhost:49858 | dbname | Sleep   |  339 |       | NULL
     |
|  4 | root   | localhost:50175 | NULL   | Query   |    0 | init  | show process
list |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------
-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> kill 2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

what is happening here is simply showing the process list of all processes running by mysql using `show processlist` command.
then simply preform `kill`command on the process Id as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL workbench is started in safe mode, and can’t update or delete, without aWHERE condition, see the error message.

To fix it, in menu, selects Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Queries, uncheck the Safe Updates check-box.